# Toggle View Height with transition / animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i want to toggle the height of a view when I press a button. I tried several things:

1. Button with transition (but I think this solution isn't good)
2. A Slider which one changes the height (like I want it, but I want to toggle between two values)

Here my current Swift File:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextView2: View {
    @State private var ChangeFrame2 = false
    @State private var height: Double = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if ChangeFrame2 {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 400)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.red)
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
        } else {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: height)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.green)
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
        }
        
        Button("Press to show details") {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.00)) {
                ChangeFrame2.toggle()
            }
    }
        
        Slider(value: $height, in: 10...500)
        Text("\(height, specifier: "%.0f") Height")
        
}
}
```

I also tried the following:

```
.background(ChangeFrame2 ? (maxHeight: 400) : (maxHeight: 600))
```

but it doesn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: You just want to change the height, with a smooth animation? If so, why is that move transition also there?

Comment: Thank you! Your Code helped me a lot. The move transition was there because I tested different possibilities ... but yours is the right one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have one `Text` view, using the ternary operator to decide the height and background color.

The problem is that when you use `if`, the two views now have different identities which breaks animations. You also have an unwanted move transition.

Code:

```
struct TextView: View {
    @State private var changeFrame = false
    @State private var height: Double = 200

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(height: changeFrame ? 400 : height)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(changeFrame ? Color.red : Color.green)

            Button("Press to show details") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                    changeFrame.toggle()
                }
            }

            Slider(value: $height, in: 10...500)

            Text("\(height, specifier: "%.0f") Height")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]